# What is the purpose of code consoles in JupyterLab?

Tags: jupyter-lab

I was exploring JupyterLab and one thing that still confuses me is code consoles. At this point it is unclear how one might benefit from using them since they provide nearly the same functionality as notebooks.

According to the [documentation](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/code_console.html) the difference between code console and Jupyter notebook is that

> The cells of a code console show the order in which code was executed in the kernel, as opposed to the explicit ordering of cells in a notebook document. Code consoles also display rich output, just like notebook cells.

I presume that the idea behind the code console is that one might test and refine the code before running it in the notebook. However one might still do all the same within notebooks, for instance by creating another cells for testing purposes and removing them later if needed which makes code consoles redundant.

Am I failing to see the usefulness of the code consoles when writing a code?

Comment: I use the console to avoid clutter in the main notebook. Creating new cells to experiment eventually leads to a total mess, imo. If the project is big, then it'll soon become confusing what cells to keep and what to delete.

Comment: @Alex Thanks for the reply, you confirmed my assumption.